Unable to mount '/metadata'
I am using MiMax2 and trying to flash crdroid ROM with TWRP.
While formatting data, this error shows up:
unable to mount '/metadata'

When sideloading through ADB, it shows error:
assert failed update_dynamic_partitions(package_extract_file( dynamic_partitions_op_list )) 

When mounting with command mount /metadata, it shows following error:
mount: /dev/block/mmcblk0p62 -> metadata: invalid argument

Is there a way to solve the problem? Till now, no solutions in other forums are unable to solve my problem.

The ROM you had installed before formatting was a stock ROM or a custom ROM?

It was a stock ROM (default ROM with Xiaomi devices)

Self answering my question,
I needed to flash Retrofit Dynamic Partitions ROM before flashing main crdroid ROM.
